# Добавление сети ip адресов в бд

Tags: php, html, mysql

Интересует каким образом можно реализовать добавление сети ip адрессов в базу mysql согласно нижеследующему примеру:

Пусть пользователь вводит в поле input значение 192.168.0.1/16 и по сабмиту формы
в таблицу mysql добавляется диапазон ip адрессов от 192.168.0.1 до 192.168.255.255

Comment: каждый адрес из диапазона в отдельную строку в БД ?

Comment: да, именно так

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Любой IP адрес может быть представлен числом. Как шестнадцатиричным так и десяти.
255.255.255.255 = FFFFFFFF = 4294967295

У MYSQL есть готовые функции которые переводят IP-адрес из строки в числовое представление и наоборот. INET_ATON -- адрес в число INET_NTOA число в адрес.

Рекомендуется хранить ИПишники в виде чисел. И вбивать диапазоны очень легко:

```
циклом от INET_ATON('192.168.0.1') до INET_ATON('192.168.255.255')
```

Comment: а как оформить соответствующий цикл при input 192.168.0.1/16 ?
заодно, так как таблица связана с другими, хранить ip адреса в моем случае удобнее хранить в обычном виде(192.168....)

Comment: Прочти Википедию http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8
Раздел CIDR. Там написано сколько нужно прибавлять к IPишнику при разных значениях единичной маски, то что после слеша.

Comment: в рекурсии в зависимости от маски подсети.
for($i = 0; $i < 256; $i++){

}

Comment: благодарю за помощь

Comment: Если ты хочешь, чтобы я рассказал как распарсить такую строку "192.168.0.1/16" то создавай соответствующий вопрос с пометками Regexp

Comment: @Антон Лакотко, там регулярка не нужна. Explode по слешу, проверить коректен ли IP в первом элементе массива (filter_var с параметром FILTER_VALIDATE_IP), проверить, что во втором элементе массива число (integer)

Comment: @Deonis см. мой ответ на новый вопрос. Я там всё это указал. explode имеет минусы в силу того, что он просто разделяет строку по слешу. Регулярка вносит дополнительную валидацию. И даже после регулярки необходимо проверять IP на выход за границы.

Comment: > explode имеет минусы в силу того, что он просто разделяет строку по слешу

@Антон Лакотко, мде... Ну, спишем это на то, что на улице лето и вчера было воскресенье.

Comment: @Deonis я думал, что пояснять не придётся. И так ведь понятно, что имелся ввиду explode c первым параметром '/' .

Comment: @Антон Лакотко, я тоже думал, что пояснения не нужны о том, что в случае, если можно обойтись без регулярок, то и [нужно без них обходиться][1].

   [1]: http://ideone.com/waNet3